# Problem importing scenes/objects into environment

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I installed moveit from the repo and am running it with ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 13.04 (although I've also tried on 12.04). Things seem to work fine with the pr2 tutorial. I followed the same steps to configure a schunk 7 DOF manipulator and then roslaunch demo.launch from that config.

Everything seems ok except that I cannot import anything into the environment. When the select file dialog box appears, it isn't able to navigate through folders. It's strange because I can do it (although slowly) with the pr2 demo.launch.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/86916/problem-importing-scenes/objects-into-environment/) by [Chipper10](https://answers.ros.org/users/7401/chipper10/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In case anyone else has this problem, it turns out that it was a symptom of my link meshes being comprised of multiple separate meshes per file rather than one mesh. Once I joined all the meshes, the problem went away.

---

Originally posted by [Chipper10](https://answers.ros.org/users/7401/chipper10/) with karma: 41 on 2013-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0